# Custom fonts - performence issue

Tags: android

I've created a countdown timer which uses a custom textView and a custom font
the timer itself works fine, but all the other parts of the app are a bit laggy (which wasn't a problem with the default font).

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    private static Typeface myTypeface;
    private static float strokeWidth;

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (myTypeface == null) {
            myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/blow.ttf");
            strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        setTypeface(myTypeface);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = getPaint();
        int color = paint.getColor();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        setTextColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `super.onDraw` twice, it might be the reason.

Comment: Seems that you are right, my onDraw makes it slower, which is a problem since i need it to create a stroke around the text.